# How do I access my google chrome sync'd bookmarks on my iPhone while I'm out n about?

Tags: bookmarks

I once used Foxmarks, then delicious and now google chrome bookmarks.

I think each one has sucked in different ways, but i'm at a stage where i'm using google for hosting all my core info, it makes to put bookmarks with them too.

Delicious just never innovated in chrome, and stayed a FF thing.

I like google chrome bookmarks cos they're with my google account and they sync nicely and quickly. Organization is nice too. Oh, and free

But how do I access it from afar?

Answer (score 1):

Ever use X-marks? I use it for firefox and it's free and easy. Whenever you close firefox it syncs. If you need to access it from a different browser, you just go to xmarks.com and put in a name and password, and it takes you to your bookmarks as clickable links.